# Need to login twice for redirection php and mysql

Tags: php, redirect, mysqli, authentication

Hi I am trying to redirect the user to other page once he logs in but its not redirecting on first login its **redirecting on second time login**. Here is my code.

**index.php**

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['user'];
        $password=$_POST['pass'];
        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
        $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' and password='{$password}'";
        $select_user_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(!$select_user_query)
        {
            die("Connection failed".mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query))
        {
            $db_user_id=$row['id'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
            $db_user_email=$row['email'];
            $db_user_password=$row['password'];
        }
        if($username ===  $_SESSION['username'] && $password ===$db_user_password)
        {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                 window.location = \"titles.php\"
            </script>";
        }else{
            echo "<p style='color:#FF7B81'> enter correct username and password <p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the code for **titles.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            window.location = \"user_details.php\"
        </script>";
        /* header("Location: user_details.php");*/
    }
?>
```

Comment: So what's the output for the first time trying to login?

Comment: Its been refreshed and staying in index.php only then after if I login again its been redirected

Comment: use php redirect instead of javascript redirect

Answer (score 0):

Change your titles.php to:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
} else {
    header("Location:user_details.php");
    exit;
}
```

Or other solution in your index.php :

```
if($username ===  $_SESSION['username'] && $password ===$db_user_password)
{
    header("Location:user_details.php");
    exit;
}
```